# How to Change Sql Developer's Encoding?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, oracle-sqldeveloper

Whenever I try to change the character encoding on Sql Developer a loading symbol appears:

[image]

I have not been able to change the encoding anywhere in the program. How can I change the encoding to UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change my jdk to java 7